# Missing assembly after add Json.net components in Android project

Tags: components, xamarin.android

i'm trying to add Json.net to my project, so i used Xamarin Component Store to search and add Json.net component in my app. After component was added and shown in list, no reference to its dll was created and so i'm unable to use Newtonsoft namespace in my app.

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You may have to add the dll yourself. Does the component show in your components folder in the mono droid application? Did you go to the component store through the application itself or just download the component from outside of the application?

The component only supports up to .NET 4.0 are you on 4.5?

Source Component Compatibility: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Comment: I'm using .net 4.0 and downloaded component by Xamarin Studio. Component is present in component's folder but not dll was referenced. I've downloaded restsharp dll from github and referenced it manually. Now error afflict System.dll version: restsharp needs v4.0, but in mono framework is present v2.0. Any idea?

Comment: No. I have to say I am not sure. When I add the Json.Net component to my Xamarin.Android project I automatically get a Newtonsoft.Json reference. Might want to figure out where your componenets go when you download them .. it could be an issue with default project location?

Comment: Solved! I've created a new project within new solution and now it works. Thank you